# tweepy twitter api stream status objects vs api search status objects - timestamp_ms / created_at difference?

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

is there documentation on the tweepy streaming api that describes why the timestamp_ms as well as the created_at fields are present in the json, and why for tweepy search api the timestamp_ms attribute is excluded but created_at is given?

i have a small mini library of helpers to standardize a bunch of my twitter api operations.  i was surprised when i started passing my mini library of helpers tweepy search status objects that it threw an error saying no timestamp_ms attribute is there.  i searched a few diff times for sort of a 'reason' here and want to better understand the "why" and also to sort of confirm what i am seeing as i inspect these objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `create_at` field is present in all tweet status objects (returned by search or streaming). It's the date/time stamp of when the tweet was created.

The `timestamp_ms` is present only in the real time stream and indicates when the object that contains the timestamp  was added to the stream. It is not necessarily a tweet status object. Could be a deletion event, for example.

More info here...
https://twittercommunity.com/t/adding-new-features-to-streaming-api/15214

Comment: is it fair to say that the streaming API returns a dict, whereas the search API returns an object of which there is a _json dict in there?

Comment: so streaming API returns a dict, whereas the search API returns an object in which a _json dict is an attribute?  i planned to make a single object that would be my generic tweet object- that could normalize a streamed tweet or searched-for-tweet.  now i am digging in w ur help and i see that created_at is 1a. a string inside the json of a searched tweet 1b. a datetime object an attribute of the searched tweet and 2. a string inside the dict that a streamed tweet returns.  i guess normalizing these is not worth it- they are so similar but also different that it's more confusion than efficient

Comment: Streaming API returns a continuous stream of dicts. Most of these dicts are tweet objects. Some are not. Search API returns a single dict which has a field 'statuses'. The 'statuses' field is an array of dicts. These dicts are all tweet objects.

Comment: AFAIK 'created_at' is always a string.